# "Unable to locate phpcs" error in Visual Studio Code

Tags: php, windows, visual-studio-code

Can someone help me solve a small problem with Windows? I've always used Linux or Apple and have never had this problem.

Issue Type: **Bug**

phpcs: Request workspace/configuration failed with message: Unable to locate phpcs. Please add phpcs to your global path or use composer dependency manager to install it in your project locally.

VS Code version: Code 1.29.1 
OS version: Windows 10

Answer (score 3):

As you say it says phpcs not located which can mean one of two things either you don't have phpcs installed or you haven't specified the path in VS Code

If you do have it installed you may follow these instructions.

1. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> to open the VS Quick Dialog.
2. Type **ext install phpcs** to find the extension.
3. Press Enter.
4. Restart VS Code when prompted to.

If you haven't installed it yet. 
1. Install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md).
2. Require PHPCs by typing

> **composer global require squizlabs/php_codesniffer**

in the terminal.  
3.Follow steps above.

Information found at [Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ikappas.phpcs)

Comment: Just a small note, the CTRL + B command opens the list of files, not the Quick Dialog.